# Перетащить файлы с удаленного сервера на локальную машину

Tags: linux, клиент-сервер, scp

Помогите разобраться, как перетащить данные с сервера на ноутбук. 
Видимо, не совсем понимаю, как работает команда `scp`.

Пробую запускать команду на сервере:

> scp local_machine_name@local_machine_adress.com:file_from_server /directiry/in_local_machine

`local_machine_name` и `local_machine_adress` взял из второй строчки файла `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте данные не из `/etc/hosts`, а обращение по IP. Узнать его можно так:

```
ip -o addr show
```

Запустите на ноутбуке команду

```
scp <имя_пользователя_сервера>@<IP_сервера>:/путь/к/файлу/на/сервере .
```

Эта команда скопирует файл в текущий каталог. Если нужно копирование в другой каталог - напишите путь к нему вместо точки.

Если будут проблемы с подключением, то вам нужно будет проверить, что в правилах сетевого фильтра разрешено подключение по SSH с Вашего IP и что в настройках демона SSH нет запрета на подключение этого пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Запустите на локальной машине: `scp server_user@server_adress:/path/to/file_from_server /directiry/in_local_machine`

Comment: Правильно ли я понял место, откуда нужно брать server_user и server_adress? У меня вышло: connection timed out

Comment: server_user - это имя пользователя на сервере, server_address - адрес сервера (доменное имя или IP)

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь также использоваться rsync
**rsync -avz username@ipaddress:/path /path**

Answer (score 0):

#### SCP

`scp osticket.ru.1.9.4.pre2.zip super@192.168.100.85:/home/super`  ### перекидываем файл на удаленный сервер

`scp ваш_логин@имя_хоста.ru:file.txt /некоторая/директория`   ### забираем файл с удаленного сервера